# How to perform manual IPC null check

Tags: android, ipc

I have an android application for testing purpose. I was trying to learn how android apps can be freed from security vulnerabilities. From my primary research I came to know about IPC null DoS attacks. This vector can be used by attackers to deny the services provided by the compromised app.

Is it possible for me to test manually for IPC null inputs whether the app is vulnerable DoS of this kind? Is it necessary to decompile the apk and look at the code to find this vulnerability? I am looking for a solution without digging into the codes.

Surprisingly, I couldn't find any methodologies by Googling. :(